# Where is cached RDD stored (i.e. in a distributed way or on a single node)?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

When we cache an RDD in Spark, is it then stored in a distributed way or on a single node? In which systems memory is it stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data remains distributed and is not stored in a single node after a cache operation. The `cache` or `persists` option doesnt change/affect the distribution of an `RDD`. the distribution  per and post cache operation remains the same.

Comment: So, the distributed data that is persisted, is stored in the memory of its own respective nodes?

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you pls answer this question also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351229/what-does-the-shuffling-phase-actually-do)

Answer (score 3):

`cache` is a lazy operator (it's more a hint than a transformation or an action in RDD sense).

Quoting the scaladoc of [cache](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@cache():RDD.this.type):

> **cache(): RDD.this.type** Persist this RDD with the default storage level (MEMORY_ONLY).

When a Spark application is submitted for execution (using `spark-submit`) it requests Spark executors. Quoting the official documentation's [Components](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html#components):

> Once connected, Spark acquires executors on nodes in the cluster, which are processes that run computations and store data for your application.

Every executor starts its own BlockManager (with BlockManagerMaster hosted on the driver). Quoting [Mastering Apache Spark](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-blockmanager.html) gitbook:

> BlockManager is a key-value store for blocks of data (simply blocks) in Spark. BlockManager acts as a local cache that runs on every "node" in a Spark application, i.e. the driver and executors.

Once you execute an action, it triggers loading the dataset from external data sources and the data starts flowing through the Spark distributed computation pipeline.

That's when the data gets cached in every BlockManager that participates in the computation. Their number is exactly the number of partitions of the RDD that was cached and can be checked using so-called [RDD lineage](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-rdd-lineage.html):

> **RDD Lineage** (aka **RDD operator graph** or **RDD dependency graph**) is a graph of all the parent RDDs of a RDD. It is built as a result of applying transformations to the RDD and creates a logical execution plan.

You can see the RDD lineage of a Spark computation using [RDD.toDebugString](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@toDebugString:String):

> **toDebugString: String** A description of this RDD and its recursive dependencies for debugging.

One could be as follows:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(0 to 9).groupBy(_ % 3).flatMap { case (_, ns) => ns }
scala> rdd.toDebugString
res4: String =
(8) MapPartitionsRDD[7] at flatMap at <console>:24 []
 |  ShuffledRDD[6] at groupBy at <console>:24 []
 +-(8) MapPartitionsRDD[5] at groupBy at <console>:24 []
    |  ParallelCollectionRDD[4] at parallelize at <console>:24 []
```

(`8` partitions are due to `local[*]` master URL that I used to start `spark-shell` with `*` mapped to the number of CPU cores on my machine)

Actually, the number of BlockManagers in use is the number of tasks per stage (in a Spark job) and could be as many as the number of Spark executors. It varies per stage.

Wrapping up...

> When we cache an RDD in Spark, is it then stored in a distributed way or on a single node?

Distributed way, but could happen to be on a single node if the number of partitions in a stage is 1.

> In which systems memory is it stored?

In "systems memory" of the Spark executor that hosts the BlockManager which happens to be in charge of RDD blocks.

---

RDD is a description of a distributed computation and is "gone" when DAGScheduler (that runs on the driver) maps it to TaskSets per stage with as many tasks as partitions.

RDD and partitions "disappear" once you execute an action and are transformed into stages and tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you pls answer this question also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351229/what-does-the-shuffling-phase-actually-do)